# Docker: Rediect container port to host without binding it

Tags: docker, sockets

One of my Docker container ports needs to be redirected to the host, like with this parameter: `-p 1234:4321`. This works great for something like port 80 which I open via browser.

But if I have ports I want to permanently bind on my host machine I get into trouble, because docker already bound that port on my host.  If I want to bind that port on my host machine I get exceptions like: `Address already in use: NET_Bind`.

How can I tell Docker to just reroute traffic to the host port without binding that port?

Comment: How many apps do you have in the same host? this seems like a use case for nginx as a reverse proxy

Comment: What do you expect to happen to the server that's currently listening on the port?

Comment: Actually I think I found the solution via "host.docker.internal". I just contact this address from inside the container and reach the host that way. I will post that as answer if it works.